# Get user friendly date android

Tags: android, date, system

Hi i want to Get System Date In User Friendly Manner Like February 14, 2011 12:00 AM. How can I do this in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can use SimpleDateFormat class in which you can get Date and time as you want. You can write something like this

```
Configuration mConfiguration = new Configuration();
Settings.System.getConfiguration(getContentResolver(), mConfiguration);
final TimeZone mTimeZone = Calendar.getInstance(mConfiguration.locale).getTimeZone();
SimpleDateFormat mSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd HH:mm");
mSimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(mTimeZone);
mRefreshDateTime = mSimpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Where in SimpleDateFormat you can pass as you like. You can find the class parameters from here: [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
I hope it would help you.

Comment: I want to get date like February 14, 2011 12:00 AM. How?

Comment: Hi Herry. You can use "MMMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm a".

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar mReminderCal = Calendar.getInstance();
mReminderCal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date dateText = new Date(mReminderCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1900,
    mReminderCal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
    mReminderCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
    mReminderCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
    mReminderCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
String dateString = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", dateText));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 1):

[SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) like in Java SE

Comment: LOL same answer from number of users :D